# Events not dispatched in frontend / unable to observe a frontend event

Tags: event-observer, ee-1.14.2.4

I'm trying to observe the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event so that I can filter out products with a certain attribute on the frontend (whether a product is discontinued). I am able to observe the event in the adminhtml scope, but not frontend. Code as follows:

etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jps_ProductDiscontinuation>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Jps_ProductDiscontinuation>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <jps_productdiscontinuation>
                <class>Jps_ProductDiscontinuation_Model</class>
            </jps_productdiscontinuation>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <jps_productdiscontinuation>
                        <class>jps_productdiscontinuation/observer</class>
                        <method>filterOutDiscontinued</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </jps_productdiscontinuation>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

/Model/Observer.php:

```
class Jps_ProductDiscontinuation_Model_Observer {
    public function filterOutDiscontinued(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        Mage::log("Event observed ~ jps 7/21/2017");
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
//        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('discontinued', array('eq' => 'yes'));

        return $this;
    }
}
```

<s>I don't believe it's an issue with my code because I logged the output of the `dispatchEvent` method in Mage.php while loading a category list on the frontend and `catalog_product_collection_load_before` was never dispatched, only in admin. This is on a dev server with settings that might vary slightly from production. Any idea what might suppress the event on the frontend or some sort of event related setting that might be related?</s>

Edit: the event *is* dispatched and dispatch is confirmed through logging `dispatchEvent()`.

Update: Per @sv3n's advice I installed Firegento and determined that the observers were not actually recognized. Through changing:

```
<class>jps_productdiscontinuation/observer</class>
```

to:

```
<class>Jps_Discontinuation_Model_Observer</class>
```

I was able to get them to appear in the Firegento observer list, but they're appearing under the incorrect module. Magento thinks they're part of the `Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog2` module in the community code pool when they're part of their own module in the local code pool.

Comment: You are trying this at catalog view page?

Comment: Correct - maybe it's not the right event?

Comment: It should be there .... use it on my own. (1.9CE)

Comment: I'll log the output again of dispatchEvent() and verify - maybe I missed it

Comment: Can you try `catalog_product_collection_load_after`? Both should be fired.

Comment: Okay, they _are_ dispatched. I didn't grab enough of the output last time. Which leaves more confused - why would it observe it in adminhtml but not frontend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62598/discussion-between-derivative-and-sv3n).

Comment: Tested your code ... and it works on frontend. So please make sure all extension files are in correct place and extension is loaded. I've no further idea so far.

Comment: Thanks @sv3n. The extension is definitely loaded correctly, it must be due to a conflict with something else, and that's a rabbit hole to go down. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: No :) I'm happy about every accepted answer, but as long it's not resolved, it should stay open. And I'm interessed in what causes this, so please leave a comment when you've found the reason. :)

Comment: Is there maybe another observer on same event with same name? You can try https://github.com/firegento/firegento-debug to check if your observer is recognized.

Comment: there's another observer acting on the same event and possibly interrupting flow, I'll investigate that and then check out firegento, thanks @sv3n

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Updated information in question

Comment: Okay ... seems to be rewrite conflict. Please check module rewrites in firegento module. Or post other modules config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jps_ProductDiscontinuation>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Jps_ProductDiscontinuation>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <jps_productdiscontinuation>
                <class>Jps_ProductDiscontinuation_Model</class>
            </jps_productdiscontinuation>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <jps_productdiscontinuation>
                <class>Jps_ProductDiscontinuation_Helper</class>
            </jps_productdiscontinuation>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <Jps_Productdiscontinuation_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>jps_productdiscontinuation/observer</class>
                        <method>filterOutDiscontinued</method>
                    </Jps_Productdiscontinuation_Observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do anything. There's no helper defined - I'm not sure what including it in the config is supposed to do? Changing the scope of the event observer doesn't help because it's the frontend that I cannot view the events in.